# Type "ViewController" does not conform to protocol "UITableViewDataSource"

Tags: swift

I've broken down in my first couple of pages of trying to learn swift. Getting this error.

Here is the code. What basic thing have I done wrong?

```
class ViewController : UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {

    var restaurantNames = ["Cafe Deadend", "Homei", "Teakha", "Cafe Loisl", "Petite Oyster", "For Kee Restaurant", "Po's Atelier", "Bourke Street Bakery", "Haigh’s Chocolate", "Palomino Espresso",
        "Upstate", "Traif", "Graham Avenue Meats And Deli", "Waffle &  Wolf", "Five Leaves", "Cafe Lore", "Confessional", "Barrafina", "Donostia", "Royal Oak", "CASK Pub and Kitchen"]

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, NumberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        //Return the number of rows in the section
        return restaurantNames.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)  -> UITableViewCell {

        let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        // Configure the cell...

        cell.textLabel?.text = restaurantNames[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You have an uppercase N in numberOfRowsInSection. Should be:

```
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        //Return the number of rows in the section
        return restaurantNames.count
    }
```

Comment: Good eye, and a reason to let autocomplete work its magic for you!

Comment: Thanks! I'll have a look on Monday :)

Comment: Yup!

This was it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you get this error it means the class you made does not adhere to the protocol you are saying it inherits.

What does that mean? It means that you inherited UITableViewDataSource and that has an associated protocol. It has methods it expects you to create that match its protocol (requirements).

Look at the requirements for this class here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/index.html

And look where it says required by 2 methods:

```
tableView(_:cellForRowAtIndexPath:)
 Required


and


tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)
 Required
```

Implement those methods and you'll be good to go!

Comment: Thanks! I'll have a play on Monday! Appreciate the heads up.