# Type "ViewController" does not conform to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource"

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting an error when coding, saying

> Type "ViewController" does not conform to protocol "UITableViewDataSource"

Can anyone tell what went wrong with this?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource{

    let devCourses = [
        ("Math"),
        ("Science"),
        ("English"),
        ("Computer Programming"),
        ("Physics")]
    func numberOfSectionsInTableview(tableview: UITableView)-> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableview(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) ->Int{
         return devCourses.count
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()

        let (courseTitle) = devCourses[indexPath.row]

        cell.textLabel?.text = courseTitle
        return cell
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to change the parent to UITableViewController?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Type “ViewController” does not conform to protocol “UITableViewDataSource”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28241279/type-viewcontroller-does-not-conform-to-protocol-uitableviewdatasource)

Comment: I put "tableview" instead of "tableView" and that was why i made the error. thanks guys for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common mistake, please make sure you use the correct words. In your case it should be:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     return devCourses.count
}
```

not

```
func tableview(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return devCourses.count
}
```

You must use *table**V**iew* instead of *table**v**iew*. It is case sensitive

Answer (score 3):

I think you are missing some functions for that are required by the delegate:

The declaration should be changed to include:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
```

and then you make sure all the required methods for a table are there:

```
func tableView(tableView:UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section:Int) -> Int
```

and

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell!
```

and invoke delegate on `ViewDidLoad`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

      yourtableview.dataSource = self

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Hope this helps